# Ayuda con el error: Indice fuera de los limites de la matriz

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una base de datos con una tabla de la siguiente estructura

```
id int
producto varchar
tipo int
1 float
2 float
3 float
4 float
5 float
6 float
...hasta 52
```

Ahora lo que necesito es que al seleccionar un numero de un dropdownlist (Semana1.SelectedValue), el cual tienen números del 27 al 52, al igual que los campos de mi tabla, debo inicializar una variable con el numero elegido del dropdownlist y contar 9 números consecutivos a partir del elegido, ahora lo que hago es llenar un array iniciando por el numero elegido y contando hasta 9 números mas, pero en mi for me indica el error del titulo.
El los for puse <=52 porque 52 es el numero máximo al que puede ser llenado el array, y tambien si al llegar el array llega al 52 pero faltan mas numeros para llenarlo debera regresar desde el 1

Al final como pueden ver puse un foreach el cual lo necesito para leer los números que se cargaron en el array, para saber en que columna guardar ciertos datos, de la manera en que lo tengo repite el mismo numero en todas.

```
int sem1 = Convert.ToInt32(Semana1.SelectedValue.ToString());
string query = "";
double cjs = 0;
int[] valores=new int[9];
int i;
if (double.TryParse(cantidad.Text, out cjs))
{
    if (Producto.SelectedValue == "PAPEL")
    {
        if (Tipo.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            if (sem1 == 52)
            {
                for (i = 1; i <= 52; i++)
                {
                    valores[i]=i;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = sem1; i <=52; i++)
                {
                    valores[i]=i;
                }                              
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (int y in valores)
    {
     query = "INSERT INTO Tbl1 (producto,tipo," +"[" + y + "],[" + y + "],[" + y + "],[" + y + "],[" + y + "],[" + y + "],[" + y + "],[" + y + "],[" + y + "])" +"VALUES (@producto,@tipo@s1,@s2,@s3,@s4,@s5,@s6,@s7,@s8,@s9)";
```

}

Comment: ¿Si el número elegido es 17, que esperas tener al final en el array?. ¿Y si el número elegido es 48?

Comment: si es 17 debe haber en el array [17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25] y si es 48 [48,49,50,51,52,1,2,3,4]<- si sobrepasa el 52 que es mi nimero limite debera regresar desde el 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes hacer un ciclo que itere solamente 9 veces, que son las posiciones de la matriz. Y calcular el valor a almacenar en cada posición. Una forma fácil de comprender, aunque no la más óptima, sería por ejemplo:

Para *leer* los valores, puedes volver a iterar por el arreglo `valores`, o utilizar un `foreach`, como lo hago yo más adelante.

Te dejo un ejemplo con un programa de consola, al que asigno directamente el valor de la semana de inicio. Puedes adaptarlo a tu entorno para tomar el valor de la semana de inicio del combo box, como en tu pregunta.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int semanaInicio = 48;
        int[] valores = new int[9];

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
          if (semanaInicio + i <= 52)
            valores[i] = semanaInicio + i;
          else
            valores[i] = semanaInicio + i - 52;

        }
        foreach(int valor in valores) {
            Console.WriteLine(valor);
        }   
    }
}
```

La salida de este programa en la consola es:

```
48
49
50
51
52
1
2
3
4
```

Puedes probar este código en [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hV0AsO)

Comment: gracias por su aporte, ahora para leer esos datos como lo hago?

Comment: Edité mi pregunta para mostrarte como acceder a los valores con un `foreach`.

Comment: Hola, garcias pero como agregaria cada numero al query de mi insert? :c

Comment: Estimado, tu pregunta era sobre el índice fuera del rango de la matriz. Considero que ese tema está cubierto. Sobre ya utilizar cada número en un SQL, sugiero que intentes resolverlo por ti mismo a partir de este punto. Si tienes alguna duda adicoinal, puedes plantear nuevas preguntas, pero la idea es que te esfuerces en realizar tus tareas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes definido el array de 9 posiciones pero intentas llenarlo con tantas posiciones como haya entre el mumero elegio, o el 1 si eligio el 52, y 52.

Ademas recuerda que los arrays inician en el indice 0, por lo que int[] valores=new 
int[9]; sera valore[0]....valores[8], valores[9]=xxx daria error "Out Of Bounds Exception"

Si lo que quieres es llenar nueve lugares desde el numero elegido, con un limite en 52 
seria algo como

```
if (sem1 == 52)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        valores[i]=i;
    }
}
else
{
    int semx = sem1;
    for (i = 0; i <=9 && semx<=52 ; i++; )
    {
        valores[i]=semx;
        semx++;
   }
}
```

Si lo que buscas es que al llegar a 52, si no llenaste los 9 elementos continuar desde el 1, entonces debes elimnar el && semx<=52 y poner un if dentro del bucle que ponga en 1 el semx cundo sea >52.

Comment: gracias por su aporte, ahora para leer esos datos como lo hago?